# Store unchecked checkbox data

Tags: database, laravel

I cant seem to figure out how to store unchecked checboxes  value in my DB.

i have this in my view

```php
{{Form::label('user_photo', 'Valodas',['class' => 'control-label'])}}
            Latviešu {{Form::checkbox('val[]', 'Latviesu',false)}}
            Angļu {{Form::checkbox('val[]', 'Anglu',false)}}
            Krievu {{Form::checkbox('val[]', 'Krievu',false)}}
```

And here is my controller function to store data

```php
if($req->input('val') == null){
    $valoda = "";
} else {
    $valoda = request('val');
}
```

And in my database im only getting the value of the values that are checked
[image]

I need the 3rd value so that in my update view i could set values to checked or unchecked for each value

Comment: As how HTML works with checkboxes and inputs, you are not going to receive any unchecked checkbox, so you will have to know the hole and then remove the checked ones to get which one is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column for each checkbox, you can do it this way;

```
$latviesu = array_has($req->val,'Latviesu')?1:0;
$anglu = array_has($req->val,'Anglu')?1:0;
$krievu = array_has($req->val,'Krievu')?1:0;
```

checking that the array from the request has the value

But to be honest, I would rename the checkboxes so that they are not in an array

Answer (score 0):

Quick reminder in Laravel 5.6 You can check if checkbox is checked by

```
$request->has('yourCheckboxName');  / return true / false
```